# Is it possible with Local Notification to trace the GPS(latitude and longitude) of specific Place?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, uilocalnotification

Using LocalNotification can we trace the particular Location and when we enter in that area i should get the Notification?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using the region monitoring built into iOS since 4.0.

```
[locationController startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

This will trigger one of 2 methods depending if you are entering or exiting this region.

```
-didEnterRegion
-didExitRegion
```

From here, you can trigger an alert (if in the foreground) or a local notification (if in the background) and pass whatever information you'd like in the notification.

There are plenty of tutorials out there to hold your hand through setting this up. Just look for CLLocationManager, CLRegion, and the region monitoring methods associated with them. It's a piece of cake.

Comment: I got your point but assume I have Quit the App from background and now i want to perform this task using LocalNotification then is it Possible?  Thanks for Response.

Comment: The app wouldn't have to be quit, just running in the background. The delegate methods will get called no matter what state the app is in. I would get that part working first, then add the notifications after that.

Comment: Yes that i know if we put App in background then we can achieve this task but my requirement is App should be Quit and I should get the notification like Push notification.Please share your thoughts if it's possible.

Comment: Like my other comment said, yes, it is possible. Your app will get 'woken' up by the geofence event and you can trigger the local notificiation that way. No need to work push notifications into the app if you don't need to.